# How to add light theme and dark theme to Vaadin tooltip?

Tags: html, css, typescript, vaadin, vite

I'm using Vaadin tooltip component like this in my html:

```
      <h1 id="heading-2">
        salam
        <vaadin-tooltip
          theme="dark"
          for="heading-2"
          position="bottom-center"
          text="Tooltip with position bottom-center"
        ></vaadin-tooltip>
      </h1>

      <h1 id="heading-3">
        salam
        <vaadin-tooltip
          theme="light"
          for="heading-3"
          position="bottom-end"
          text="Tooltip with position bottom-end"
        ></vaadin-tooltip>
      </h1>
```

and I want to change the background color of the tooltip based on the theme.

The `tooltip.ts` currently looks like this:

```
import { registerStyles } from "@vaadin/vaadin-themable-mixin";
import { css } from "lit";

registerStyles(
  "vaadin-tooltip",
  css`
    :host[theme="dark"] {
      font-family: var(--lumo-font-family);
      // background-color: yellow;
    }
  `
);

registerStyles(
  "vaadin-tooltip-overlay",
  css`
    :host {
      font-family: var(--lumo-font-family);
      // background-color: yellow;
    }

    :host::part(overlay) {
      // background-color: red;
    }
  `
);
```

I don't know how to give styles to overlay based on the class that tooltip has. I also don't know how to add the class to the overlay.

I am open to adding the styles statically inside the html too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tooltip implements a custom mechanism for forwarding class names to its overlay by using the `overlay-class` attribute:

```html
<vaadin-tooltip overlay-class="custom-tooltip" ...></vaadin-tooltip>
```

The corresponding CSS rule needs to be put into the global CSS (instead of using `registerStyles` as in your example):

```css
vaadin-tooltip-overlay.custom-tooltip::part(overlay) {
  background: green;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just one thing. Do you know of a better way than adding it to the global css?

Comment: I guess it should also work with `registerStyles` for `vaadin-tooltip-overlay` and using a selector like `:host.custom-tooltip [part='overlay']`. Apart from that since Vaadin 24 we specifically made everything themable globally and recommend that over injecting styles into the component's shadow DOM.